# How to get LinkedIn URN

Tags: linkedin-api, integration, urn

I am trying to set up sharing of post via application.

As per doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin
I have created an app. And I need to have a URN. But I cannot find in docs where from I can get URN.
How can I define it? I couldn't find an aswered question like mine here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to post an info in an organization account in LinkedIn, for example, announcement info.
As per doc I need to send a post request with URN inside it. I am struggling to get this URN first.

Comment: I already have set an application with OAuth 2.0 scope w_member_social. And I have get organization page verified.